# Band structure of nonlinear Schrodinger equation with one dimensional potential

Tags: matlab, computational-physics, mathematica, electromagnetism

I have a nonlinear Schrodinger equation which reads:

$$ \frac{1}{2} \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+ |u|^2u + V(x)u = -i \frac{du}{dz},$$

where $V(x)=\cos(wx)+ i a \sin(wx)$ and $w$, $a$ are numbers.

How to solve its band structure, meaning its dispersion relation?

The plane wave expansion method is used for a real potential. Can it be applied for this complex potential also?

What are other methods, if any, in Matlab or Mathematica or other software?

Comment: welcome to scicomp! please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: I think that you should not have a source term to compute the dispersion relation

Comment: @ Kirill : Yes you're right, it was just a typo.